# TAOCP pairwise independence exercise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is exercise 6 from The Art Of Computer Programming [Volume 4 Pre-Fascicle 5](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc5a.ps.gz).

"Consider $n \ge 2$ random Boolean variables $X_1 ... X_n$ with the following joint distribution: The vector $x_1 ... x_n$ occurs with probability $1/(n-1)^2$ if $x_1+\dots+x_n=2$, with probability $(n-2)/(2n-2)$ if $x_1+\dots+x_n=0$, and with probability $0$ otherwise. Show that the variables are pairwise independent (that is, $X_i$ is independent of $X_j$ when $i \ne j$); but they are not $k$-wise independent for $k > 2$."

The answer claims that "the probability that $X_j = 1$ is clearly $p_1 = 1/(n-1)$". I couldn't understand how we reach this conclusion.

Instead, we have

$\begin{split}
1 & = \sum_{k=0}^n Pr(x_1 + \dots + x_n = k) \\
  & = Pr(x_1+\dots+x_n = 0) + Pr(x_1+\dots+x_n = 2) \\
  & = (n-2)/(2n-2) + 1/(n-1)^2 \\
\end{split}$

We can solve for $n = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation at the end of the question is wrong. The probability for the sum of the variables to take a certain value is not the probability for a particular string with that sum to occur; it's that probability times the number of strings with that sum. Thus

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^nP(X_1+\cdots+X_n=k)
&=&
P(X_1+\cdots+X_n=0)+P(X_1+\cdots+X_n=2)
\\
&=&
1\cdot\frac{n-2}{2n-2}+\binom n2\cdot\frac1{(n-1)^2}
\\
&=&
1\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

You can't solve that for $n$ because the sum is equal to $1$ independent of $n$; that's just the condition that the given probability distribution is properly normalized. Rather,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X_j=1)
&=&
E[X_j]
\\
&=&
\frac1nE[X_1+\cdots+X_n]
\\
&=&
\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^nkP(X_1+\cdots+X_n=k)
\\
&=&
\frac1n\left(0\cdot\frac{n-2}{2n-2}+2\cdot\binom n2\cdot\frac1{(n-1)^2}\right)
\\
&=&
\frac1{n-1}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you explain why $E[X_j]$ can be expanded into $\frac{1}{n} E[X_1 + \dots + X_n]$?

Comment: @JiayuanMa: $E[X_j]=\frac1n\left(E[X_1]+\cdots+E[X_n]\right)=\frac1nE[X_1+\cdots+X_n]$. The first equality uses the fact that the distribution is symmetric under permutation of the $X_i$, so all $X_i$ have the same expected value; the second equality uses the linearity of expectation.